# Get controller#index with joins to pass with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a Lead model

```rb
# A Lead is a type of User that might be interested in using our service.
class Lead < User
  validates :first_name, presence: true
  has_many :notes, dependent: :destroy

  def self.search(search)
    ...
  end
end
```

A Lead inherits from a User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :location, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :location

  delegate :address, :city, :state, :zip_code,
           :full_location, :latitude, :longitude,
           to: :location, allow_nil: true
end
```

All Users have one `Location`, which includes data like `:address, :city, :state`, etc.

I have this controller

```rb
class LeadsController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :sort_column

  def index
    @leads = Lead.search(params[:search])
                 .joins(:location)
                 .order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}")
                 .page(params[:page])
                 .per(8)
  end
end
```

I have this test

```rb
describe LeadsController, type: :controller do
  before do
    @lead = create :lead
  end

  describe 'GET #index' do
    it 'populates an array of leads' do
      get :index
      assigns(:leads).should eq [@lead]
    end
end
```

The spec *fails* and says `@leads` is empty.

The spec *passes* when I delete the line `.joins(:location)` in the `LeadsController`

Everything works fine in `development`. The app is able to pull up all the correct data and display it.

For some reason, `.joins` in the `test` environment causes `@leads` to be empty.

I need that line. I need it to be able to sort Leads(Users) by their zip_code. Remember, zip_code is stored in a `Location` object.

My question is: How do I get my spec passing while keeping sortability for zip codes? What's happening differently in the `test` environment?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried putting the `.joins(:location)` before the `.search`?

Comment: @mmichael I have. Still fails.

Comment: What does your factory look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your test sets up a `Lead` without a `Location`. Note that `joins` performs an `INNER JOIN`, so it's going to pull all the leads that have an associated location. Leads without a location will **not** be returned.

This is a nice example from the Rails [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/joins):

```
User.joins(:posts)
=> SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "posts" ON "posts"."user_id" = "users"."id"
```

You can do:

```
before do
  @lead = create(:lead)
  create(:location, user: @lead)
end
```

and your test should pass.

Comment: You're right Accepted your answer. Facepalmed for forgetting about that. Also learned that Leads without a location will not be returned. Thank you!